# safari html render issue

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, uikit

I'm stuck on a problem displaying the site in Safari on iOS. The problem occurs not on all devices. Maybe someone faced with such a problem?

Reality <--> Expectations

[image]

I created jsfiddle with all environment as needed for checking.

http://jsfiddle.net/287f6d60/2/

I think, that problem causes: `padding-bottom: 100%`

Because there is used `padding-bottom: 100%` to preserve 1:1 ratio, when images is not loaded yet.

Comment: It will be helpful if  u can  put all your code in jsfiddle... post the link here.